# Unable to build connection cloud connection in Node.js using aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2 package

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core

Using this [aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/) aws package to make connections to the cloud and I am facing an issue while creating a build with the configuration builder.

I am using [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/tree/main/samples/node/basic_connect) simple basic connect example to connect (I used it in my application with some changes in the flow of code):

So, I modified the flow of starting this execution, I called the below method from my **myProject/index.ts**:

```
export function initializeCloud() {
    const cloud_args = {
        endpoint: 'someEndPoint.amazonaws.com',
        client_id: 'TestingClientId',
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'AmazonCertificate.crt')),
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'AmazonPrivateKey.key')),
        ca_file: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'AmazonRootCA.pem')),
    };
    main(cloud_args);
}
```

and **main()** function I have passed this **cloud_args**:

```
async function main(argv: Args) {
    const connection = build_connection(argv);

    const timer = setInterval(() => { }, 20 * 1000);

    console.log("Connecting...");
    await connection.connect()
    console.log("Connection completed.");
    console.log("Disconnecting...");
    await connection.disconnect()
    console.log("Disconnect completed.");

    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

From the main function, I called below **build_connection()** method:

```
function build_connection(argv: Args): mqtt.MqttClientConnection {
    let config_builder = iot.AwsIotMqttConnectionConfigBuilder.new_mtls_builder_from_path(argv.cert, argv.key);

    if (argv.proxy_host) {
        config_builder.with_http_proxy_options(new http.HttpProxyOptions(argv.proxy_host, argv.proxy_port));
    }
    if (argv.ca_file != null) {
        config_builder.with_certificate_authority_from_path(undefined, argv.ca_file);
    }

    config_builder.with_clean_session(false);
    config_builder.with_client_id(argv.client_id || "test-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000));
    config_builder.with_endpoint(argv.endpoint);
    // console.log('config_builder: ', config_builder);
    const config = config_builder.build();

    const client = new mqtt.MqttClient();
    return client.new_connection(config);
}
```

In this method, I have used predefined methods and in the last line: 35, I am getting the below error:

```
Fatal error condition occurred in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\aws-crt-nodejs-build-dll-win64\aws-crt-nodejs\crt\aws-c-common\source\allocator.c:210: allocator->mem_release != ((void *)0)
[start:dev] Exiting Application
[start:dev] at 0x7FFC2F82EA70: napi_register_module_v1
[start:dev] at 0x7FFC2F82EA70: napi_register_module_v1
[start:dev] at 0x7FFC2F82EA70: napi_register_module_v1
[start:dev] at 0x7FFC2F82EA70: napi_register_module_v1
[start:dev] at 0x7FFC2F82EA70: napi_register_module_v1
[start:dev] at 0x00007FFC2F82D090: Failed to lookup symbol: error 487       
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725E659A0: node::Stop
[start:dev] at 0x7FF7266F2120: v8::internal::Builtins::code_handle
[start:dev] at 0x7FF7266F2120: v8::internal::Builtins::code_handle
[start:dev] at 0x7FF7266F2120: v8::internal::Builtins::code_handle
[start:dev] at 0x7FF7266F2120: v8::internal::Builtins::code_handle
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726776890: v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap
[start:dev] at 0x7FF72665FE80: v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm
[start:dev] at 0x7FF72665FCA0: v8::internal::Execution::Call
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726742C00: v8::Function::Call
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725ECE2C0: node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725ECE2C0: node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725E64EE0: node::Start
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725ECC040: node::LoadEnvironment
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725DDA880: cppgc::internal::NormalPageSpace::linear_allocation_buffer
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725E64EE0: node::Start
[start:dev] at 0x7FF725C33900: RC4_options
[start:dev] at 0x7FF726CDD070: v8::internal::compiler::RepresentationChanger::Uint32OverflowOperatorFor
[start:dev] at 0x7FFC6F637600: BaseThreadInitThunk
[start:dev] at 0x7FFC6FA22680: RtlUserThreadStart
[start:dev] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am unable to build the connection using the **config_builder** using this **aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2** package

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks
Anand Bundela

I am expecting that I need to connect the cloud using this code flow.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I am getting `Fatal error condition occurred in /aws-crt-nodejs/crt/aws-c-common/source/allocator.c:210: allocator->mem_release != ((void *)0)` and am not sure of the source

Comment: Did either of you figure this out? I'm getting the same error with the `call` function